# What does this light mean on renault clio 2007

Tags: renault, clio, dashboard-lights

[image]

Hello this light (the little car with a pin thing behind it) has come up on my nephews car, it is a birthday present for his 17th, its his first car and we don't know what this light is. Sorry if its something very simple we don't know much about cars lol.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching the 'net for the [owners manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1205594/Renault-Clio-2007.html?page=53#manual) for this model and year results in a listing showing that the display represents the distance traveled since the trip meter was last reset. A similar display represents the average speed since last reset. image from linked page:

[image: page from manual showing icons]

Comment: So it's a trip odometer?

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: No so much as a trip odometer, although that is one function. It's the first I've seen of a multi-function presentation feature in a motor vehicle. Our newest vehicle is ten years old, which makes that reference somewhat invalid.

Comment: This isn't correct. The display above is showing 105.2 gallons - the G symbol underneath - so the display is showing the quantity of fuel used since the last reset.

Comment: Gallons in a European motor vehicle? The tiny fuel pump (in the 398 image above) is missing.

Comment: @fred_dot_u UK market vehicles use gallons because the fuel economy is calculated in miles per gallon, despite fuel being sold by the litre (yes, it's complicated). The fuel pump icon only appears for the remaining range display (in miles) - I'm talking about the fuel used since the last reset. Since 2018 I've owned a 2005 Renault Grand Scenic which works exactly like this.